# Registering click handlers with browser back/forward buttons

Tags: html, event-handling, navigation, single-page-application, browser-history

I am building an HTML5 single-page web app that employs the concept of "views" or "screens"; essentially just different DOM elements rendered to be visible at any given time. As the user navigates between "views", I'm really just hiding/enabling DOM elements.

I'd like to be able to make use of the browser's history functionality, including the back/forward buttons, but I'm not sure how that plays into the concepts of `history.pushState` and `window.onpopstate`.

Ideally, I'd like to register "click handlers" with the browser's back/forward history buttons (obviously in a cross-browser-compatible way) so that when the user clicks either button, it engages my own custom `Historian` object (in JavaScript) that figures out which "view" to render for the user.

How can I do this?

Comment: ...and if what I'm asking here isn't possible, I'm also interested in any solution via the HTML5 "History API"...

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need some sort of routing solution. You can use [Crossroads](http://millermedeiros.github.io/crossroads.js/) to register and manage your routes. Each route should have a handler, which enables the appropriate div in your single page.

```
var route1 = crossroads.addRoute('/page1/', function(id){
  //enable div for page1 route
});
```

Then, you can use [Hasher](http://github.com/millermedeiros/hasher/) to manage browser history.

Another way is to rebuild your application with [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/), which has a router and manages browser history out of the box.

Comment: Thanks @Erikas Pliauksta (+1) - but I'm interested in a "homegrown" solution here so that I can really understand the History API here. Do you know what part of Hasher has the code in it for responding to users clicking the back/forward buttons? Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure if hasher uses history API at all. They suggest to look into [Historyjs](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js) for History API solutions. I guess, you can learn a lot about History API by examining history.js source code.

Comment: It looks like `window.onpopstate` can be used for handling the back button - is this true? If so, what is the equivalent for the forward button? I would have *expected* to see something like `window.onpushstate`, but there is no such method...